# How to find consecutive/successive objects in a list of objects

Tags: python

I have a list of object that have attributes serial number (SN) and datetime along with others. From how the list is generated, the objects should be in chronological order.
Cronologically, objects can have the following SN:

1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,3,...

How can I retrive the first an last timestamps of all consecutive sequences of SN. For example for SN=1 that would be the first to fith timestamp as well as the 17th and 24th to 26th.
Same for all SNs that appear in the list of objects.
What I want to go for is a Gantt like Diagram to show at which times these SNs were present.

Comment: As I see it, you have two options: a list comprehension (http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)  or to use filter (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
def consecutive(nums, sn):
    count = {nums[0]: [[0]]}
    for idx, num in enumerate(nums[1:]):
        if num == nums[idx]:
            try:
                count[num][-1][1] = idx + 1
            except IndexError:
                count[num][-1].append(idx + 1)
        else:
            try:
                count[nums[idx]][-1][1] = idx + 1
            except IndexError:
                count[nums[idx]][-1].append(idx + 1)
            try:
                count[num].append([idx + 1])
            except KeyError:
                count[num] = [[idx + 1]]
    return count[sn]
```

test:

```
test = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3]
print consecutive(test, 3) # will return [[8, 14], [21, 23], [26]], which are the index ranges for SN = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this code does it. I am still trying to figure out what it happening here. Another question: how do I do if i want to get the indices of the first of a series or a single SN and then the first of the following different sn (or last of the SN if no others are following)? so for SN= 3, in my example it should result in [[8,14],[21,23],[26]].

Comment: Basically I keep updating a dictionary called `count` while iterating the given list. If it goes into the `else` block, means current `num` is different from the previous one. To make this change, in the `else` block, you need to update the previous one (`count[num[idx]]`) before making changes on count[num]. I just updated my solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will now work my way through the code you provided!

Comment: I found one issue here, if I add another 1 at the end of the list, and run it for SN = 3, it should return [[8, 14], [21, 23], [26,27]], but it doesn't. Similar when I run it for SN = 1, it should return [[0, 5], [16,17], [23, 26]], but it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, missed that one. Now it should be fine. Anyway these many try-except blocks in my code are kind of ugly. If you get the idea, maybe you can replace them with some proper `if` statements and handle edge cases in a better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate this!